# Unable to change font size on UILabel in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, size

I have recently started learning iOS programming. I am working on a demo application in which I am using font "`GE Flow Regular`"(GE_Flow_Regular.otf) & "`GE Flow Bold`" for an arabic language. I have followed all the required steps to add a custom fonts in iOS app.
I want to increase or decrease the size of the texts on a `UILabel` in iOS but I am unable to do so with this specified font. I can easily perform font size increase or decrease with other fonts in iOS. I don't understand why I am unable to change font size with "`GE Flow Regular`" font?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please, share your code, on both successful and unsuccessful cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]`?

Comment: Yes I have done that as already mentioned in the question about tried using all the required process to set a custom font.